# How to position a UIAlertController's view?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm writing an app in Swift, targeting iOS 8. Does anyone know whether it's possible to programmatically position the alerts that are displayed via [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIAlertControllerStyle)? The documention makes no mention of position or location, so I tried setting the controller's `view.frame` property to a new `CGRect`, but alerts still appearing dead center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alert view, by design, shows right in the center. This is because the experience is intended to be familiar and simple for the end user. In the documentation for `UIAlertController` it also notes:

> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

If you wish to manipulate the placing of the frame, you've got several options that use a plain old UIView/UIViewController. Here is one I've used where you can do what you want that's written in swift: https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift